# CURL Get Request with a parameter that contains a GET url

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, curl, facebook-php-sdk

I'm trying to make a cURL `GET` to scrape a Facebook Graph object:

```
GET https://graph.facebook.com/?id=**OBJECT_URL**&scrape=true&method=post
```

In my case, `OBJECT_URL` contains `GET` parameters:

```
https://www.example.com/og.php?a=b&c=d
```

For that reason I can't have it as a `GET` parameter in `file_get_contents()` or `CURLOPT_URL`, as it'd turn out something like this:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/?id=**https://www.example.com/og.php?a=b&c=d**&scrape=true&method=post
```

Is there a way to pass it as a `GET` parameter in a way similar to `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You need to escape your parameters, the [http_build_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) function will be useful:

```
$query = http_build_query([
 'id' => 'http://foo?a=1&b=2',
 'scrape' => true,
 'method' => 'post'
]);

$url = "https://graph.facebook.com/?".$query;

var_dump($url);
```

This will output:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/?id=http%3A%2F%2Ffoo%3Fa%3D1%26b%3D2&scrape=1&method=post
```