# How to pass GET parameters in curl PHP

Tags: php, json, curl, php-curl

I am new to `PHP` development. I am working on `CURL` to call my `WEB API`. As a newbie I found very hard to understand things.

**How my API is working**

API_URL is `http://localhost:14909/api/meters/GetByMsn/002999000077/2017-10-11T12:16:20`

It takes a `meter serial number` and a `data time` and gives the response by `authorizing` the URL. The response I get is

```
{
"data": {
    "Response": "No"
  }
}
```

**What I want to do**

Now In `PHP` I am using [CURL](https://support.ladesk.com/061754-How-to-make-REST-calls-in-PHP) to make the request. The request is simple as it takes the current selected `meter serial number` and a `current date time` also it should take authorization key.

**What I have done till now**

Below is the code so far i have done

```
    if( isset($_REQUEST['selected_meters']))
    {
        $m = MetersInventoryStore::findOne($_REQUEST['selected_meters']);

        $msn = $m->meter_serial; // current selected meter serial number is saved

        $date_time =  str_replace(' ','T',date('Y-m-d H:i:s')); // current date time

        $api_url = 'http://116.xx.xx.xx:xxxx/api/meters/GetByMsn/'; // my base URL

        $curl = curl_init($api_url);

        curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: MY_KEY')); // setting the authorization key in header.


        exit();

    }
```

Now I want to send the `meter serial number` and `date time` parameters. For this I have searched many articles but all I found a way to pass parameters as [query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32596799/6854117) and [related link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13371369/6854117).

One method I am thinking of is passing parameters direct to the URL Like:

```
$api_url = 'http://116.xx.xx.xx:xxxx/api/meters/GetByMsn/[$msn]/[$date_time]';
```

OR

```
$api_url = 'http://116.xx.xx.xx:xxxx/api/meters/GetByMsn/' + $msn + '/'+$date_time;
```

But I don't know will it works or not

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Try and learn yourself.

Comment: http://116.xx.xx.xx:xxxx/api/meters/GetByMsn/?msn=$value_msn
Use the "?", search for the rest

Comment: @DessaugesAntoine can't use `?` as the parameters are passed like a path

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile I have already taken look into it and also have referred in my question that parameters are passed like a path not as a query

Comment: `+ $msn +` php concat by + how? use . operator to cocat the string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a lot of searching I manage to get a response. Concatenate both of the parameters in the `URL` and changing the `curl_setopt`.

Changes:

From

```
 $api_url = 'http://116.xx.xx.xx:xxxx/api/meters/GetByMsn/'; // my base URL
```

To

```
 $api_url = 'http://116.xx.xx.xx:xxxx/api/meters/GetByMsn/'.$msn . '/' . $date_time; // my base URL
```

And

```
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: MY_KEY')); // setting the authorization key in header.
```

To

```
curl_setopt($curl CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: MY_KEY')); // Removed the CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER
```

And then

```
$curl_response = curl_exec($curl);
         print_r($curl_response);
       /* print_r($msn);
        echo $date_time;*/
        //echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        exit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out and see if it works:

```
$api_url = 'http://116.xx.xx.xx:xxxx/api/meters/GetByMsn/${msn}/${date_time}';
```

or

```
$api_url = 'http://116.xx.xx.xx:xxxx/api/meters/GetByMsn/{$msn}/{$date_time}';
```